# How to make horizontal alignment for characters in grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, alignment

I have a LaTeX script that renders characters within a grid. While it functions adequately, there is a minor problem where the alignment of characters is disrupted if some of them occupis a considerably smaller space.

```tex
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./} }
\setCJKmainfont{Kaiti SC}
% \setCJKmainfont{Xingkai SC}
% \setCJKmainfont{STKaiti}

\newcommand\Grid[1]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
  \draw[xstep=1ex,ystep=1ex,help lines] (-1ex,-1ex) grid (1ex,1ex);
  \draw[help lines,densely dash dot]
  (-1ex,-1ex) -- (1ex,1ex)  (-1ex,1ex) -- (1ex,-1ex);
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (char) at (0,0) {#1};
 }%
}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \Huge 芙蓉楼送辛渐 \\
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
    \huge 唐 $\bullet$ 王昌龄 \\
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    \Huge 寒雨连江夜入吴 \\
    \Huge 平明送客楚山孤 \\
    \Huge 洛阳亲友如相问 \\
    \Huge 一片冰心在玉壶 \\
\end{center}
\hrule
\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{芙}\Grid{蓉}\Grid{楼}\Grid{送}\Grid{辛}\Grid{渐} \\
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
    \huge \Grid{唐} $\bullet$ \Grid{王}\Grid{昌}\Grid{龄} \\
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{寒}\Grid{雨}\Grid{连}\Grid{江}\Grid{夜}\Grid{入}\Grid{吴} \\
    \Huge \Grid{平}\Grid{明}\Grid{送}\Grid{客}\Grid{楚}\Grid{山}\Grid{孤} \\
    \Huge \Grid{洛}\Grid{阳}\Grid{亲}\Grid{友}\Grid{如}\Grid{相}\Grid{问} \\
    \Huge \Grid{一}\Grid{片}\Grid{冰}\Grid{心}\Grid{在}\Grid{玉}\Grid{壶} \\
\end{center}
% \hrule
% \newpage
% \begin{figure}
%     \centering
%     \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{image.jpg}}
% \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: 芙蓉楼送辛渐]

See the one magnified, it is breaking the alignment, This issue is likely occurring because the magnified characters occupy less space. To address this, how can we apply alignment to ensure consistent positioning of the characters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to `anchor` the nodes that contain the characters as well. So, you could add `anchor=base,yshift=-0.7ex` to the options of the node, for example.

Comment: Another way to solve this would be to add a `\strut` inside the node. But you'd also need to shift the node a bit, I'd assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set the `anchor` for the node that contains the character or make sure that the node has the same height, regardless of its contents. You might need to shift the node a bit vertically to align it correctly with the grid.

To different solutions:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setCJKmainfont{FandolKai}

\newcommand\Grid[1]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
  \draw[xstep=1ex,ystep=1ex,help lines] (-1ex,-1ex) grid (1ex,1ex);
  \draw[help lines,densely dash dot]
  (-1ex,-1ex) -- (1ex,1ex)  (-1ex,1ex) -- (1ex,-1ex);
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,yshift=-0.7ex] (char) at (0,0) {#1};
 }%
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{芙}\Grid{蓉}\Grid{楼}\Grid{送}\Grid{辛}\Grid{渐} \\
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
    \huge \Grid{唐} $\bullet$ \Grid{王}\Grid{昌}\Grid{龄} \\
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{寒}\Grid{雨}\Grid{连}\Grid{江}\Grid{夜}\Grid{入}\Grid{吴} \\
    \Huge \Grid{平}\Grid{明}\Grid{送}\Grid{客}\Grid{楚}\Grid{山}\Grid{孤} \\
    \Huge \Grid{洛}\Grid{阳}\Grid{亲}\Grid{友}\Grid{如}\Grid{相}\Grid{问} \\
    \Huge \Grid{一}\Grid{片}\Grid{冰}\Grid{心}\Grid{在}\Grid{玉}\Grid{壶} \\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setCJKmainfont{FandolKai}

\newcommand\Grid[1]{%
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
  \draw[xstep=1ex,ystep=1ex,help lines] (-1ex,-1ex) grid (1ex,1ex);
  \draw[help lines,densely dash dot]
  (-1ex,-1ex) -- (1ex,1ex)  (-1ex,1ex) -- (1ex,-1ex);
  \node[inner sep=0pt,yshift=-0.15ex] (char) at (0,0) {#1\strut};
 }%
}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{芙}\Grid{蓉}\Grid{楼}\Grid{送}\Grid{辛}\Grid{渐} \\
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
    \huge \Grid{唐} $\bullet$ \Grid{王}\Grid{昌}\Grid{龄} \\
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
    \Huge \Grid{寒}\Grid{雨}\Grid{连}\Grid{江}\Grid{夜}\Grid{入}\Grid{吴} \\
    \Huge \Grid{平}\Grid{明}\Grid{送}\Grid{客}\Grid{楚}\Grid{山}\Grid{孤} \\
    \Huge \Grid{洛}\Grid{阳}\Grid{亲}\Grid{友}\Grid{如}\Grid{相}\Grid{问} \\
    \Huge \Grid{一}\Grid{片}\Grid{冰}\Grid{心}\Grid{在}\Grid{玉}\Grid{壶} \\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output of both solutions:

[image]